# Problem with Crystal Reports when no parameters are passed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

We recently upgraded our software to a new version of Crystal reports (13.0.10 > 13.0.21). During testing everything worked fine, but once we deployed an end user brought up an issue.

All of our crystal reports are backed by stored procedures. The end users were given the ability to create custom reports. They were told that they would need to use stored procs to get any data back. Somewhere along the way one user found out that they could bypass creating a stored proc.

In that scenario they would click the button to generate the report from inside of our software.  After our software rendered the report Crystal would prompt them for a database login and then ask them for the parameters. It was slow but it worked, and the end user didn't have to learn how to write a proc.

Fast forward to the new version of Crystal we are using.  The user is still prompted to login to the database and provide parameter information, but when the report comes back none of the parameters are being enforced.

This seems like a change with in Crystal, which I would understand.  Unfortunately my boss is worried about blow back from end users because 'your new version of the application broke all of my custom reports (even though I didn't add them in correctly)'

It is worth noting that when the end users run these reports from inside of the report designer it works just fine.  When a report with a proper stored proc is run, it displays fine.

We would like to see Crystal take the late parameters and apply them before displaying the report, as it used to do.  I just have no idea where to start looking

Comment: Check [sap.wiki](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) for known issues with that version.


And please see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274849/10191493) from keltins is pertinent to your problem.

Comment: I had come across that link from keltins but it doesn't to quite address my problem.  Thank you for the link though.

Comment: can you post code, which generates the report..dummy code..so that it can be checked..if parameter code is written..also there are settings in report designer for adding deleting parameters..are they correct?

Comment: I can't post anything from the report itself as I don't have Crystal, but within Visual Studio we are just setting the path to the report file, looping through parameters and setting them (name, value), then showing the form.

In this case we have no parameters to set because the end user didn't supply them correctly, but they are in the report.

Either way this a moot point since the powers that be decided (rightly) to tell the end user they need to do it the proper way (stored procs with params).